# Meaning of a buckling sidewalk?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, interpretation

"Each time he made the turn, he saw only the white, unused, buckling sidewalk, with perhaps, on one night, something vanishing swiftly across a lawn"... p.11 Fahreheit 451

Does it mean that the sidewalk is bent (upward), as when a tree grows next to a sidewalk and distorts it to make room for its roots? But then again, it seems paradoxical that it's buckling but also unused... Any thoughts?

Comment: If the buckling is caused by tree roots (as is common, along with frost heaves) why do you think it presumes actual use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that is buckling is overloaded.

**This is a common verb to describes forces acting on metal, wood, concrete, etc. such that they lose their shape.**

buckling sidewalks means that ridges have appeared in them.

If something buckles completely, like a building, it falls down.

However, a sidewalk can buckle (have ridges appear in it) from forces acting in an upward direction and not be completely destroyed.

buckling is the result of increased compression of a material (concrete, wood, metal, etc.)

[buckling in engineering parlance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckling)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the only meaning I can ascribe to this is that the sidewalk is bending under stress.

My interpretation is that it means that it is not being maintained, and hasn't been for a long time.